# moment.js date formatting in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, momentjs

I would like to convert the createdAt date to this format: 'Mar 22 2023'.
Tried all possibilities and always getting 'Invalid Date':

```
{
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      createdAt: moment('2023-03-22T04:40:02.215+00:00').format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Mar 22 2023
      createdAt: moment('$createdAt').format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Invalid date
      createdAt: moment('$createdAt', 'MMM DD YYYY').format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Invalid date
      createdAt: moment(new Date('$createdAt')).format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Invalid date
      createdAt: moment(new Date('$createdAt'), 'MMM DD YYYY').format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Invalid date
      createdAt: moment('$createdAt'.toString()).format('MMM DD YYYY'), // Invalid date
    }
  }
```

Need some valuable help.

Comment: Use [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/), you cannot use `moment` (or any other javasctipt function) in `$project` - unless you loop over all documents with `map` or `forEach` and process them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly, but you can process the result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      createdAt: 1
    }
  }
]).toArray().map(
   x => Object.assign(x, {
      createdAt: moment(x.createdAt).format('MMM DD YYYY')
   })
)
```